# ODE: differential notation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was taught in Calculus classes that the symbol $dx$ may stand for various things, for example, when we are integrating a function $dx$ tells us that we are integrating with respect to the variable $x$. Sometimes $dx$ is the differential of a function, defined as a function of two variables, for example $dy = f'(x)dx$ is a function of both $x$ and $dx$.

I'm attending a course on Ordinary Differential Equations, and for my surprise we are working with equations such as this one:

$$(x-y)dx +xdy=0$$

I asked my teacher what does $dx$ and $dy$ stand for in this equation, he just told me to work with them as if they where numbers and whenever we find $dy/dx$ interpret it as differentiation of the function $y(x)$ with respect to the variable $x$. That is not a very satisfying answer to me, I can manipulate expressions and solve homework problems but I feel I don't quite understand it, I know it works but I don't know why it does. Is there a better way to think about it? Is there a formal definition of what these symbols stand for in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: There is a formal definition, but it's rather highfalutin and at your stage of mathematical education it is difficult to understand and not very insightful. I recommend just rolling with this notation for now and thinking about these quantities somewhat intuitively. If it makes you uncomfortable, you can always "rigorize" that expression by turning it back into a standard one of elementary calculus, saying

$$(x - y) + x \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$

Comment: @SimonS Ok, what is the formal definition? Point me to a link if you don't want to write an answer. Thank you.

Comment: E.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form

Comment: Note that one advantage of this notation is that it doesn't privilege one variable over the other: you can "divide by $dx$" to get the form @SimonS wrote, or you can "divide by $dy$" instead, getting $(x-y) \frac{dx}{dy} + x = 0$. The two equations will always describe the same solution set (in the plane).

Comment: $dx$ must be the most troublesome notation in all mathematics...

Comment: @Ian, the 'privileging' point is an good one